# How to create a trigger to increment a column when that row only one column is updated?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I need to write a SQL trigger whenever (`engage_step_user_response`) table (`response_json`)
column updated, I need to increase no of retakes by one in the retakes column. I have tried to write a SQL trigger referencing some details. But it doesn't succeed.  can anyone please help regarding this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_engage
    ON engage_step_user_response
    AFTER UPDATE
AS 
     IF UPDATE(response_json)
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.retakes = OLD.retakes + 1
```

I'm expecting whenever the response_json column is updated retakes must be increase by one.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzN62.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

You will need a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger if you want to modify the data:

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_engage BEFORE UPDATE ON engage_step_user_response 
FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN

   IF !(NEW.response_json <=> OLD.response_json) THEN
       SET NEW.retakes = NEW.retakes+1;
   END IF;
end;
```

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/02v-LSDK)

Comment: If XXX.response_json is NULL then retakes will not be altered.

Comment: Not sure will check it

Comment: there was some issues in the previous version, this one is working fine even if response_json NULL will trigger

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER increment_engage
BEFORE UPDATE ON engage_step_user_response
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.retakes = OLD.retakes + NOT (NEW.response_json <=> OLD.response_json);
```

the code is null-safe.